# How to pull out amplitude information from complex output of cpsd - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two data sets that I want to analyze using a cross power spectral density plot in MATLAB with the function `cpsd`. With the complex output of cpsd, I was wondering how I can get amplitude information out of it. I know I can get phase info by `angle(Pxy)` but I don't know how to pull the amplitude information. Thanks

Comment: If you're still around, please mark an answer as correct or provide your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `abs(Pxy)`. According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html), if `Pxy = x + i*y`, then:

```
abs(Pxy) = sqrt(x^2 + y^2) = sqrt(real(Pxy)^2 + imag(Pxy)^2)
```

**Edit:**
In light of your comment though, you are looking for the time-domain magnitude (not frequency domain, as the above will give you). [This thread](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11503/how-can-i-compute-a-time-frequency-cross-spectrum-in-matlab) from the signal processing stack exchange may be of some help. It kind of looks like the averaging that `cpsd` performs eliminates the time-domain data from the signal.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I want the amplitude of the time domain signal. The abs of Pxy is part of the power density spectrum. Plotting the frequency ouput of `cpsd` with `abs(Pxy)` will give me a frequency vs power plot.

Comment: @Fanylion, I updated my answer, but I am not sure that you can get what you want from `cpsd`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. Just as another question you might know, what is the easiest way to get the average amplitude of a noisy periodic like signal? This might be a really broad question.

Comment: @Fanylion, I think that might be too broad. There are a lot of measures of the "average" of a periodic signal. You could do something as simple as the signal mean, mean squared, or RMS in time domain. [This introduction](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonshtml/Signal/Signal2.htm) has some more info. This may be too basic for your application though.